# Add click event to color picker extender display

Tags: javascript, .net

I want to increase height of my panel when I click on my textbox attached to my colorPickerExtender. When I add my javascript function that doesn't work and that don't change the size of my panel.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbColorCode" runat="server" CssClass="textBox" MaxLength="7" onfocus="tbColorCode_ClientClicked();" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:ColorPickerExtender ID="colorPicker" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbColorCode" PopupButtonID="tbColorCode"  PopupPosition="BottomLeft" ></asp:ColorPickerExtender>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

My java script file :

```
function tbColorCode_ClientClicked() {
document.getElementById("pnlcolorChooser").setAttribute("style","Height:250px");
```

}

My import javascript :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<script src="..\Scripts\colorPickerManager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My asp panel :

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlcolorChooser" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="500">
```

Thank you